# draw rounded corner inside rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I designed one view in which i have rounded corners. and inside that view i have other view. i give rounded corners to stroke but its not effecting inside box. you can view in below screenshot.

[image]

you can see in both inside corners. there are not properly rounded shape.

so how can I do that with proper rounded shape?

below is code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(mBorderColor);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
float strokeWidth = mHeight / 30.0f;
float strokeWidth2 = strokeWidth / 2;
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
int space = 3;
int headHeight = (int) (strokeWidth + 10.5f);


Path strokepath = RoundedRect(strokeWidth2, headHeight + strokeWidth2, mWidth - strokeWidth2, mHeight - strokeWidth2, 15, 15,
                    true, true, true, true);
canvas.drawPath(strokepath, paint);


Path fillpath = RoundedRect(strokeWidth+space, headHeight + strokeWidth + topOffset-space, mWidth - strokeWidth-space, mHeight - strokeWidth-space, 15, 15,
                    true, true, true, true);
canvas.drawPath(fillpath, mViewPaint);

paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);


public static Path RoundedRect(
            float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry,
            boolean tl, boolean tr, boolean br, boolean bl) {

    Path path = new Path();
    if (rx < 0) rx = 0;
    if (ry < 0) ry = 0;
    float width = right - left;
    float height = bottom - top;
    if (rx > width / 2) rx = width / 2;
    if (ry > height / 2) ry = height / 2;
    float widthMinusCorners = (width - (2 * rx));
    float heightMinusCorners = (height - (2 * ry));

    path.moveTo(right, top + ry);
    if (tr)
        path.rQuadTo(0, -ry, -rx, -ry);//top-right corner
    else {
        path.rLineTo(0, -ry);
        path.rLineTo(-rx, 0);
    }
    path.rLineTo(-widthMinusCorners, 0);
    if (tl)
        path.rQuadTo(-rx, 0, -rx, ry); //top-left corner
    else {
        path.rLineTo(-rx, 0);
        path.rLineTo(0, ry);
    }
    path.rLineTo(0, heightMinusCorners);

    if (bl)
        path.rQuadTo(0, ry, rx, ry);//bottom-left corner
    else {
        path.rLineTo(0, ry);
        path.rLineTo(rx, 0);
    }

    path.rLineTo(widthMinusCorners, 0);
    if (br)
        path.rQuadTo(rx, 0, rx, -ry); //bottom-right corner
    else {
        path.rLineTo(rx, 0);
        path.rLineTo(0, -ry);
    }

    path.rLineTo(0, -heightMinusCorners);

    path.close();//Given close, last lineto can be removed.

    return path;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use xml in drawable

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava because i am doing lots of things in view like animation and all.

Answer (score 0):

With the way that corners are drawn, the inner part of the corner will always be of a smaller radii than the outer part of the corner. To get the right radii for the inner part you have to draw it onto the screen. In this case you have to draw the space between the Stoke Path and the Fill Path. The code below is what is needed to draw the space, if `mViewPaint` does not have a stroke width.

```
Paint spacePaint = new Paint();
    spacePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    spacePaint.setColor(mBackground);
    spacePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    spacePaint.setStrokeWidth(space*2);

Path spacepath = RoundedRect(strokeWidth + space, 
            headHeight + strokeWidth + topOffset-space, 
            mWidth - strokeWidth - space, 
            mHeight - strokeWidth - space, 
            15, 15,
            true, true, true, true);
canvas.drawPath(spacepath, spacePaint);
```

You also have to change the following line for this to work

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

to

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
```

---

Now as others have suggested you could have used either `Canvas.drawRoundRect()` or `Path.addRoundRect` and they would have done the same thing as your method `RoundedRect`.